# POST-запрос ошибка Bad Request 400 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman

Помогите решить проблему: создал проект ASP. NET, сделал миграцию, добавил Identity, скачал Postman, в нем отключил SSL сертификат, попробовал отправить POST запрос, а он мне пишет ошибку 400 Bad Request[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А без SSL по HTTP работает? `отключил SSL сертификат` если что HTTPS без SSL не работает.

Comment: Я отключал ssl и выполнял через http, потом включал ssl и выполнял по https. Разные варианты испробовал

Comment: А мы как вам должны помочь? Вот у меня не получается открыть шкаф, вам это даёт хоть какую либо информацию? А если я скажу, что не могу открыть деревянный шкаф в комнате, ибо заржавел замок? Вот у вас аналогичная ситуация, вы нам сказали лишь "не работает" и 400… код конечно мы должны выдумать свой, отладкой заниматься тоже должны мы, мысленно...

Comment: Если бы была ещё какая-то информация, я бы написал. 400 Bad Request the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax. Я даже Response получаю пустой

Comment: Уважаемый, вы говорите про вашу собственную программу, которую написали вы, которая блокирует вдруг запрос. При чем тут постмен и что либо ещё, если речь про код? А если речь про него, то где он в вопросе? И где ваши попытки сделать отладку? Читайте логи, ставь точку остановки в контроле, смотрите на результаты, смотрите что именно серверу и вашему коду не нравится.

Comment: Причём тут моя собственная программа, когда это готовый шаблон , который предлагает майкрософт. Ни единой строчки кода я не написал. Отладить тоже не получается , ибо запрос не отрабатывает

Comment: Ну вам кто ошибку даёт, постмен или сервер? Если 2-е, то почему вы разбираетесь с первым?

Comment: может у вас просто asp настроен на http?

Comment: `Ни единой строчки кода я не написал` возможно в этом и проблема.

Comment: Если я пытаюсь авторизоваться и зарегистрироваться через сайт, то все окей,все работает. Отправить http запрос не получается вообще. Делал все по гайку от метанита и майкрософт

Comment: Откройте консоль в браузере и посмотрите какие заголовки и данные, отсылает и получает клиент во время аутентификации. Что пересылается в последующих запросах к серверу в заголовках.